# Android- lollipop preview Nexus 5 is not starting in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

I am using Genymotion version 2.3.1 with oracle virtualBox. I have downloaded Samsung Galaxy S4 4.4 and Lollipop preview -Nexus 5. Samsung Galaxy S4 is starting properly but when I start Lollipop preview. It just freezes with Android boot screen. How to fix it.Thanks in advance
Screenshot:-

[image]

Comment: Hi Rajat, is the Android logo animation still running during the boot? It is supposed to show a gradient that goes from left to right. If it is effectively freezed you should send the logs to the Genymotion support, so the team can handle the problem and solve it. https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/#

Comment: Facing the same issue... The gradient moves on and on forever..

Comment: @rajat-sharma is the issue still there or has it been solved?

Comment: Issue is solved I have installed lollipop for samsung device and now it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting the Genymotion app?
It worked for me, it also takes some time before launching and since you are using a windows machine it might take longer than the mac app.

Comment: I have tried restarting Genymotion and waited for it but problem is still same.

Comment: Since the Lollipop is in BETA stage there might be something missing that prevents your emulator from loading, [See Tweet](https://twitter.com/Genymotion/status/535109868437266432) maybe you just need for an update to be released, or maybe you need to update your virtual box.

Answer (score -1):

You need to **enable** >> **Intel Virtualization Technology(VT, VT-x, vmx)** From **BIOS**